# Angular Animation being triggered only once

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I have a application which displays random quotes every 30seconds. I wanted to use angular animations to animate those quotes. The problem that I am facing is that the text is animated only first (when the page is first loaded). But instead it should animate every time quote changes.

Here's the code I've already tried

```js
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {QuoteService} from '../services/quote.service';
import {animate, state, style, transition, trigger} from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-quote-item',
  templateUrl: './quote-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./quote-item.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('changeQuote', [
      state('true', style({
        opacity: '1'
      })),
      state('false', style({
        opacity: '0'
      })),
      transition('0 <=> 1', animate('1000ms ease'))
    ])
  ]
})
export class QuoteItemComponent implements OnInit {
  changeQuote = true;
  quote = {};

  constructor(private service: QuoteService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getQuote();
    setInterval(this.getQuote, 30000);
  }

  getQuote = () => {
    this.changeQuote = false;
    this.service.getRandomQuote().subscribe( quote => {
      this.quote = quote;
      this.changeQuote = true;
    });
  }
}
```

The HTML Code:

```html
<div [@changeQuote]="changeQuote" class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col quote my-auto">
      <div class="text-center">
        <p class="text" [innerText]="quote['quote']"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="text-right" style="margin-right: 25px">
        <p style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 38px;" [innerText]="quote['author']"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have not used angular animations yet, but looking at the docs `where triggerName is the name of the trigger, and >>expression<< evaluates to a defined animation state`: I wonder if you are having problems with comparing boolean result with string state names; because you are setting `this.changeQuote = true`, but the state names are `"true"` and `"false"`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example for your animation: [quote-animation](https://angular-fmpwq6.stackblitz.io) This example only uses your setInterval to change the state of your animation.

The main problem is your subscription inside getQuote():

1. Every time you call getQuote() you open a new subscription. (Or is your Observable completed after 1 emit).
2. Therefore a subscription is not called when your setInterval triggers the function -> It is called whenever your service results a getRandomQuote()
3. Also we do not know how your getRandomQuote() looks like. This is all a conjecture.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that @angular's change detection is not capturing the switch from true => false => true (the changes are made before the change detector has a chance to do anything). If you put a delay on your service subscription, you'll see the animation:

```js
getQuote = () => {
  this.service.getRandomQuote().pipe(
  tap(_ => this.changeQuote = false),
  delay(1000)).subscribe(quote => {
    this.quote = quote;
    this.changeQuote = true;
  });
}
```

See this demo: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xt4eyn?file=src/app/app.component.ts)